# Unable to Position Dropdown above other body elements

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

As you can see below, the dropdown menu is not positioned over the other body elements such as the timer. I'm using bootstrap for dropdown and redcountdown js for the timer.

[image: Screenshot of the current problem]

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6 m-t-15" style="border-left:1px solid #fff;"><center>
    <h3 class="material-animate">
    <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-width="200px" id="d_d" style="text-align:center"><option><center>Select</center></option></select>
    Delegate Time</h3>
    <div id="delegate_time" class="redCountdownDemo material-animate"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="ttime form-control material-animate" placeholder="DD" id="dtd"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="ttime form-control material-animate" placeholder="HH" id="dth"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="ttime form-control material-animate" placeholder="MM" id="dtm"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="ttime form-control material-animate" placeholder="SS" id="dts"></div>
    </div><br>
    <span class="btn btn-success material-animate" id="d_update"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Update</span>
    <span class="btn btn-danger material-animate" id="d_reset"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Reset</span>
    <div class="checkboxer form-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" value="" id="mspeak">
        <label for="mspeak">MSpeak</label>
    </div>
</center></div>
```

I have tried to work around position and z-index of all the elements, but nothing happened to work. So I have reset all the CSS modifications to the initial state.

Please help me position the dropdown menu above all the other elements of the body.

For complete code, visit: https://github.com/lightofindia1/DiPSMUN-Moderator-App

Comment: I would say that it must be z-index and positon:relative,absolute for elements. Maybe dropdown is a child of div which has lower z-index then div with charts ?

Comment: You need to provide a working code snippet that reproduce the issue, no one has any interest to parse though all your code

Comment: Also, the `<center>` tag was deprecated for ....a looooong time ago...

Comment: ... and it is not valid with elements inside an `<option>`, like `<option><center>Select</center></option>`

Comment: @LGSon I'll remove the center tag, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these two styles to your css files (maybe the bottom of `elements.css`) or somewhere you want to override the previous ones:

```
.display-animation .material-animate {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

.display-animation h3.material-animate {
    z-index: 2 !important;
}
```

You will achieve what you want!